# Ruby Net:HTTP::Get weird behavior with JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rest, net-http

I am using `Net::HTTP` for sending `GET` request to an API Server to fetch some data based on some configurations as below:

```
# method to fetch shirt sample details from api server
def fetch_shirt_sample(shirt, query_params)
  path = "http://myapiserver.com/shirts/#{shirt.id}/shirt_sample"
  url = URI.parse(path)
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path + '?' + query_params)
  res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) { |http| http.request(req) }
  JSON.parse(res.body)
end
```

What is wrong or weird I found is above method works for following query params:

```
"&name=medium_shirt&color=red&configs=[\"full_length\",\"no_collar\",\"casual\"]"
```

but doesn't even send `GET` request for following query params:

```
"&name=medium_shirt&color=red&configs=[\"full_length\",\"15\",\"43\",\"30\"]"
```

Could anyone help me to understand what is wrong in the above setup?

Comment: "doesn't even send" means what exactly?  An exception?  The code just literally does nothing?

Comment: Yes no exception at server or client side.